# Function does not display correct values

Tags: php

I am using function to display all values from tables but the ones that are checked in another table to be checked.

I am trying to print all values from one table, print them in checkbox. Then I am using this function to display all values and mark values checked if they are selected in another table.

```
function emarketing_oprema_checked(){
  $id = test_input($_GET['id']);
  $link = new mysqli("localhost", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
  $link->set_charset("utf8");
  $sql=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT a.OpremaId, a.OpremaNaziv, b.Oprema, b.Partner 
    FROM jos_ib_emarketing_oprema a 
    LEFT JOIN jos_ib_emarketing_stavke_oprema b ON a.OpremaId = b.Oprema where Partner = $id  ");

   while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
     $data='<input type="checkbox" name="oprema[]" value="'.$record["OpremaId"].'"';

   if(isset($record['Oprema'])) {//field in the database
         $data.=' checked="checked';
       }
       $data.='">'. $record["OpremaNaziv"] .'</br>';
    echo $data;

    }

    }
```

As a result I got only checked values, not the ones that are not checked.

Here is my form

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
  <input type="checkbox" id="oprema" onclick="Exposeoprema()">Oprema<br>
      <div id="Scrolloprema" style="height:150;width:200px;overflow:auto;border:1px solid blue;display:none">
       <?php
        emarketing_oprema_checked();
         ?>
      </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: your question is unclear.. what you need to achive.. whether you need all the checkbox value? or only the checked checkbox

Comment: Where is your form part and need more information?

Comment: I have added explanation

Comment: `'checked="checked';` should be `'checked="checked"';` and `$data.='">'` should be `$data.='>'`otherwise if checked false u get a extra `"` inside input tag.

Answer (score 0):

The `isset($record['Oprema']` will always be true, even if the value of it is `null` because the field is exists.

You need to check the value of it.

Try:

```
if ($record['Oprema']) {
    $data.=' checked="checked';
}
```